# Provisioning lite monitoring plan fails with "not allowed to provision non-lite plan"

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-monitoring

"Lite org is not allowed to provision non-lite plans"

Even though I'm requesting a lite plan it tells me I'm trying to provision a non-lite plan.

I've tried this through the console AND the CLI. CLI command was:

`bx cf create-service Monitoring lite my_monitoring_service`

Is the MONITORING service not available for lite plans even though it has a lite plan option?

Comment: Based on the documentation, this issue looks like a defect. Let me reach out to the Monitoring service team.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bug - on my list of things to fix this week.

You don't really need to provision a lite plan for the monitoring service.  Any platform metrics that are published by services are available directly from the monitoring service URL via `https://metrics.<env>.bluemix.net` ( ie. https://metrics.ng.bluemix.net ).

The provisioned instance within the bluemix console provides you with the  launching point to access the monitoring service UI via the Launch button and the ability to upgrade to a paid plan (which won't be possible from the lite account).

The workaround for you to view the platform metrics in the mean time is to launch directly against https://metrics.ng.bluemix.net ( or other regional endpoint ).

Comment: thanks John, ok so I'll try to start sending metrics to it without provisioning. btw. what i want to do is use jthomas' npm module: https://github.com/jthomas/ibm-cloud-monitoring to send metrics.

Comment: seems there is still some issue with lite / payed plans. I just sent metrics and received the response: {"errors":[{"code":"BXNMSRI01E","message":"Metrics can only be accepted on a paid plan"}]}